# Laravel set between digits in validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

in simple use rules of laravel validator i want to check input for between 1 and 10.

this below role do not work correctly and accept zero

```
'required|integer|digits_between:1,10'
```

or

```
'display_post_count' => 'required|min:1|max:10',
```

Comment: It's just `between:min,max` not `digits_between` See: http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-between

Comment: @FDL this `required|integer|between:1,10` is correct. thanks

Comment: Added as answer so the question can be closed. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: @naththedeveloper between does not work without the integer rule

Comment: @peter my answer has integer in it... see the answer not the comment

Comment: @naththedeveloper I didn't mean it's wrong. It's something that everyone has to aware of

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You seem to be using `digits_between` but you need to be using just `between` ([docs](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-between)).

```
'item' => 'required|integer|between:1,10',
```

Comment: just saying that using digits_between costed in my application some stolen bitcoins, because `digits_between` does not work at all. now your answer works well.

Comment: For  some reason `'item' => 'between:1,10` doesn't work

Comment: Between works, you just need to have the integer validation as well.

Comment: for simple : `'item' => 'required|between:1,10'`, will work

Comment: Data range example from 1 to 100, then use like `'item' => 'min:1,max:100'`. It will work :)

Comment: When it's coming from html form it is treating as string.

Answer (score 28):

You should use digits_between when you are trying to get exact same "length". for example to validate if user input is a digit between 0 to 99, you just add "digits_between:1,2" in your validation.

```
'item' => 'required|digits_between:1,2',
```

If your number is decimal, and want to validate if entered number is a range number between 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, ... to 2, you need use "numeric|between:1,2" in your validation.

```
'item' => 'required|numeric|between:1,2',
```

Comment: I think the Ideal answer is not the correct one but the the comparative and descriptive of wrong vs right + the right one , thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Try This way**

```
'your_number' => ['required', 'integer', 'between:1,10']
```

**Or**

```
'your_number' => 'required|digits_between:1,10'
```