# laravel validate controller from negative number

Tags: laravel

I want to write a validateUpdate controller in Laravel and I want the user to enter the number field from -10 to 10. i use numeric but not working
Thank you for your help.

```
protected function validateUpdate(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([

      'floor'    => 'numeric|max:10|required', 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might help you in achieving what you want:

'item' => 'required|integer|between:1,10', [(reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22302472/laravel-set-between-digits-in-validation)

For more information you can visit this link [(docs)](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation).